# Unordered list to select with 2nd child

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to make change for my code from `<ul>` to `<select>` and `<li><a href="#link"></li>` to `<option value="#link"></option>`

this is my html code

```
<ul class="navigator">
    <li class="active"><a href="index.php">HOME</a></li>
    <li class="dropdown"><a href="#">COMPANY</a>
        <ul class="navigatorChild">
            <li><a href="companyAbout.php">About Tanobel</a></li>
            <li><a href="companyFactory.php">Factory</a></li>
            <li><a href="companyResearch.php">Research</a></li>
            <li><a href="companyDistribution">Distribution</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">PRODUCTS</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">NEWS &amp; EVENTS</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">CAREER</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">CONTACT US</a></li>
</ul>
```

I saw another question in stackoverflow and I got this code to transform ul li to select option

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  function transformToJMenu(breakpoint){
    $("select.navigator").remove();
    if ($(window).width() < breakpoint) {
      $('ul.navigator').each(function(){
        var select = $(document.createElement('select')).insertBefore($(this).hide());
        $(document.createElement('option'))
          .appendTo(select)
          .val('#')
          .html('Navigate to ..');

          option = $(document.createElement('option'))
          .appendTo(select)
          .val(this.href)
          .html(
            "&nbsp;&nbsp;" + $(this).html()
          );
        });

        select.addClass("navigator");

        $(".navigator").on('change', function(){
          window.location.href = $(this).val();
        });

      });
    } else {
      $('ul.navigator').show();
    }
  }

  transformToJMenu(768);

  $(window).on('resize', function(){
    transformToJMenu(768);
  });
});
```

and it be like this

[image]

I know it's success to be what I want but how the second child like About, factory etc to be `&nbsp;&nbsp&nbsp;&nbspAbout Tanobel` instead of `&nbsp;&nbspAbout Tanobel`..

Thank you and sorry for my English

Comment: Use a optgroup :)

Comment: never bind events in loops

Comment: @madalinivascu : Aw.. Thanks.. I'm sorry about the event I think It's not necessary.. :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a optgrup

```
     $('.navigator > li > a').each(function(index) {

    if ($(this).next().is('ul')) {
      op += '<optgroup label="'+ $(this).text()+'">';
      $(this).next().find('a').each(function() {
        op += '<option value="' + this.href + '">' + $(this).html(); + '</option>'
      });
      op += '</optgroup>'
    }  else {
     op += '<option value="' + this.href + '">' + $(this).html(); + '</option>'
    }
  });
  $(select).append(op);
```

demo:

```js
function transformToJMenu(breakpoint) {

  $("select.navigator").remove();

  if ($(window).width() < breakpoint) {
    $('ul.navigator').each(function() {

      var select = $(document.createElement('select')).insertBefore($(this).hide());

      $(document.createElement('option'))
        .appendTo(select)
        .val('#')
        .html('Navigate to ..');
      var op = '';
      $('.navigator > li > a').each(function(index) {
       
        if ($(this).next().is('ul')) {
          op += '<optgroup label="'+ $(this).text()+'">';
          $(this).next().find('a').each(function() {
            op += '<option value="' + this.href + '">' + $(this).html(); + '</option>'
          });
          op += '</optgroup>'
        }  else {
         op += '<option value="' + this.href + '">' + $(this).html(); + '</option>'
        }
        
        



      });
      $(select).append(op);
      select.addClass("navigator");

      $(".navigator").on('change', function() {
        window.location.href = $(this).val();
      });

    });
  } else {
    $('ul.navigator').show();
  }
}

transformToJMenu(2000 );

$(window).on('resize', function() {
  transformToJMenu(2000);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="navigator">
  <li class="active"><a href="index.php">HOME</a></li>
  <li class="dropdown"><a href="#">COMPANY</a>
    <ul class="navigatorChild">
      <li><a href="companyAbout.php">About Tanobel</a></li>
      <li><a href="companyFactory.php">Factory</a></li>
      <li><a href="companyResearch.php">Research</a></li>
      <li><a href="companyDistribution">Distribution</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">PRODUCTS</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">NEWS &amp; EVENTS</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">CAREER</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">CONTACT US</a></li>
</ul>
```